# How do the grammatical functions of "ti" differ in: "ti pagheremo" vs "ti pagheremo un salario"?

Tags: grammar

> **ti** pagheremo per lavorare
>
> {vs}: **ti** pagheremo un salario per lavorare

```
== pay you (a salary)
```

I've just heard that the personal pronoun "ti" actually serves different grammatical functions in these two similar sentences, though they both seem like an indirect object with the meaning of "to you".

Answer (score 5):

In the first sentence, *ti* is the direct object (complemento oggetto), in the second case it is an indirect object (complemento di termine).

With the pronoun after the verb the two sentences would become

> Pagheremo **te** per lavorare
>
> Pagheremo un salario **a te** per lavorare

When the pronoun is in front of the verb it takes the form *ti* in both cases. The same opposition is in

> Ti amo (amo te)
>
> Ti voglio bene (voglio bene a te)

Answer (score 3):

The verb *pagare* has the curious, but by no means unique, feature that it can be construed in more than one way: it may admit *as a direct object* any of the following:

- the person being paid: *Ho pagato Gigi per portarmi a spasso il cane*
- the amount of money being paid: *Ho pagato un sacco di soldi per potermene stare in santa pace*
- the object being paid for: *Ho pagato questa macchina trentamila euro* (see [another question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9493/is-una-macchina-an-indirect-object-in-pagare-una-macchina-30-mila-euro-if-s))

(I believe that the two first constructions hold for English too, but this is beside the point.)

So, the first of the sentences in the question, *Ti pagheremo per lavorare* may be, a bit awkwardly, rephrased *Pagheremo te per lavorare* (as in the Gigi example), and “ti” (or “Gigi”) is the direct object.

The sentence *Ti pagheremo un salario per lavorare*, on the other hand, can be rephrased as *Pagheremo a te un salario per lavorare*, so the direct object is “un salario” here.

The misleading detail is that the pronoun *ti* is, “accidentally”, both the dative and the accusative form of *tu*. It all would be different in the third person, or with a noun:

*Lo pagheremo per lavorare*
versus
*Gli pagheremo un salario per lavorare*

or

*Pagheremo Gigi per lavorare*
versus
*Pagheremo un salario a Gigi per lavorare.*